# Problems with Snapshot for Firebase, need workaround

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on react project and am new to using firebase. Basically I am doing a query to get user's data and I want to reference it in the html but it does not let me because I am using a snapshot. I can't set data from the snapshot of the query to a global variable because I don't think it exists out of the snapshot. Is there a way to get the query's data outside of snapshot?

```
    let usersname = "";
    const myFunction = async () => {
        let user = window.sessionStorage.getItem("user");
        const q = query(accountsCollectionRef, where("username", "==", user));

        onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
            let queryData = [];
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                queryData.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
            })
           usersname = queryData[0].name;
           
        })
    }
    myFunction();
    console.log(usersname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check are response exits, this is how you do it.

```js
onSnapshot(q, snapshot => {
            if(!snapshot.empty) {
                usersname = snapshot.docs[0].data().name
            } else {
                usersname = ""
            }
        })
```

I just shortened the thing you did in your function. Check are it work, most important is `if(snapshot.exists())` this is way you check are response have data. Remember to unsubscribe snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your code and I get that an error that says snapshot.exists is not a function. I also get the same error for when i tried snapshot.empty.

Comment: @stupidCollegeStudentPlsHelp Well if it's not a function it might be a variable. Check is it  a boolean variable.

Comment: @stupidCollegeStudentPlsHelp Are you sure it is not a function? Because I see it is a function.

Comment: I can't check the type. When I do typeof(snapshot.exists) it just says undefined

Comment: I know it is a function, I think it is an error because I am using firebase/app

Comment: Oh, No! It's my mistake you are somehow using query not a doc reference.

Comment: @stupidCollegeStudentPlsHelp So if you use query use `!snapshoot.empty`

Comment: Ok thanks I did that and it works however the global variable assigned to query data still does not work outside of onSnapshot(). `
        onSnapshot(q, snapshot => {
            if(!snapshot.empty) {
                usersname = snapshot.docs[0].data().name
                console.log('Inside usersname '+ usersname);
            } else {
                usersname = "empty"
            }
        })
    }
    myFunction();
    console.log('Outside usersname' + usersname);` and it prints: Inside usersname Peter Lee
Outside usersname

Comment: @stupidCollegeStudentPlsHelp So learn first plain JavaScript if you don't know how Observables and Promises works.